# How to interpret or calculate a value from a user input in C#?

Tags: c#, node.js, entity-framework

I have to develop a Web application for a payroll system. I would like use C# and SQL server for the development. This payroll system has to calculate different formulas, which are defined by the users.

For example, the users will type in a input the text below and it will be saved in the BDD.

```
if salary > 4000 then calculateRate
```

In knowing that "salary" can be a method that calculates the salary on several months and "calculateRate" is a method too.

We can have some formulas more complicated like :

```
if salary > 5000 
then calculateRate + variable 
else if salary > 10 000
then {
calculateRate + variable + bonus
}
```

Here:

1. Salary = method
2. calculateRate = method and "variable" is a variable pay that we have to search in the database
3. bonus = a variable pay that we have to search in the database

or in the formulas the user can go to take a value in the BDD in typing :

```
if db.user_table.salary > 500
then calculateRate 
else if ....
```

I have some big questions about this developement :
 - how I can achieve it ?
 - does C# is the best solution ? or I have to use NodeJS for exemple
 - how to interpret in C# what the user will type

I need a performance solution because we will have many calculations to do.

Comment: What is your version of BDD? Doesn't sound like Behaviour-Driven Development in the context you are using.

Comment: The question is unclear. Variables and methods that calculate formulas are common in pretty much every language.

Answer (score 0):

> - how I can achieve it ?

This means that you're asking us how to create this program. Just the phrase: "This payroll system have to calculate differents formulas **and these formulas are defined by the users.**" tells me that your task is nearly impossible.

> - does C# is the best solution ?

I don't know. But I can tell you that C# is not the **only** solution

> - or I have to use NodeJS for exemple

Same answer. You need to obtain more specific instructions for what your program must do.

Comment: For exemple in JS we have eval to interpret les input but in c#I don't have this method.. Also I would like some recommandations to developp this application.

Comment: You gave us way too few details to be able to help you. All you say is that it calculates a payroll system, using some user-given formulas. Not only just programming the payroll system is hard, there are an infinite possibilities for the user to calculate it, if he chooses the formulas. After allowing the user to input the formula, it must be parsed, corrected, etc. And this is just the beginning.

Comment: Yes but the great question is how to treat formulas ?

Comment: Indeed. This is a great question.